# error in launching the emulator and android device

Tags: android, runtime-error

hi i am a new app developer, when i was trying to run my app the following occured...

```
[2011-02-24 09:33:35 - FirstImage] Android Launch!
[2011-02-24 09:33:35 - FirstImage] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2011-02-24 09:33:35 - FirstImage] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-02-24 09:33:35 - FirstImage] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

The adb is located in "`C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\`"

i tried "adb start-server" in run command but no use, is there any way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try killing the **Android Debug Bridge (adb)** by just running the command `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` on your command prompt.

Also ensure that if you have updated your SDK then path of adb may be `android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` in your new sdk. So just try copying that file in the `android-sdk-windows\tools` directory.